# PostGIS returns an empty GeometryCollection out of an intersection between a MultiPolygon and a Point

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometrycollection, multi-geometry

## Context

I've narrowed down an issue I faced involving many buffers and so on, to this in [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) (version `2.4`):

```
SELECT St_geometrytype( St_geomfromtext(
    'MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0,4 0,4 4,0 4,0 0),
                   (1 1,2 1,2 2,1 2,1 1)),
                  ((-1 -1,-1 -2,-2 -2,-2 -1,-1 -1)))'
))
```

which answers: `ST_MultiPolygon`
It's OK, I guess.

But this;

```
SELECT St_geometrytype(St_intersection(St_geomfromtext(
    'MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0,4 0,4 4,0 4,0 0),
                   (1 1,2 1,2 2,1 2,1 1)),
                  ((-1 -1,-1 -2,-2 -2,-2 -1,-1 -1)))'
), 'POINTZ (30 40 50)') )
```

answers: `ST_GeometryCollection`
A *GeometryCollection*, ok, but out of what?

I even tried to force casting it into a `Multi*Geometry` but without any success, it still outputs a `ST_GeometryCollection`:

```
SELECT St_geometrytype(St_Multi(St_intersection(St_geomfromtext(
    'MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0,4 0,4 4,0 4,0 0),
                   (1 1,2 1,2 2,1 2,1 1)),
                  ((-1 -1,-1 -2,-2 -2,-2 -1,-1 -1)))'
), 'POINTZ (30 40 50)')) )
```

## Question

I cannot figure out why this is giving a `GeometryCollection` where, obviously, it *should* return `NULL` or a "NULL first input geometry" (i.e. a `NULL MultiPolygon`)?

Comment: Could you edit the title to express that this happens when the result is empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Answer

After having parsed the different documentation pages searching for "GeometryCollection" in there, I almost gave up, until I decided to actually *read* through the page of [ST_Intersection](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html) which states:

> Returns a geometry that represents the point set intersection of the Geometries.
>
> In other words - that portion of geometry A and geometry B that is shared between the two geometries.
>
> If the geometries do not share any space (are disjoint), then an empty geometry collection is returned.

Indeed, I wasn't able to find this "geometry collection" by searching for the one word version of it!
But it's here, and clear enough.

So I may better check if it actually intersects before computing the intersection, which is done using [ST_Intersect](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html), e.g.:

```
SELECT (ST_Intersects(ST_GeomFromText(
    'MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0,4 0,4 4,0 4,0 0),
                   (1 1,2 1,2 2,1 2,1 1)),
                  ((-1 -1,-1 -2,-2 -2,-2 -1,-1 -1)))'
), 'POINTZ (30 40 50)') )
```

returns: `false`

and

```
SELECT (ST_Intersects(ST_GeomFromText(
    'MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0,4 0,4 4,0 4,0 0),
                   (1 1,2 1,2 2,1 2,1 1)),
                  ((-1 -1,-1 -2,-2 -2,-2 -1,-1 -1)))'
), 'POINTZ (0 0 0)') )
```

returns: `true`

to which, the corresponding:

```
SELECT ST_GeometryType(ST_Intersection(ST_GeomFromText(
    'MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0,4 0,4 4,0 4,0 0),
                   (1 1,2 1,2 2,1 2,1 1)),
                  ((-1 -1,-1 -2,-2 -2,-2 -1,-1 -1)))'
), 'POINTZ (0 0 0)') )
```

gives a `ST_Point`.

But I would have been able to notice the empty GeometryCollection by simply running the inner part of the first query, i.e.:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(ST_GeomFromText(
    'MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0,4 0,4 4,0 4,0 0),
                   (1 1,2 1,2 2,1 2,1 1)),
                  ((-1 -1,-1 -2,-2 -2,-2 -1,-1 -1)))'
), 'POINTZ (30 40 50)') )
```

which returns: `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY` (or  `010700000000000000` if you omit the `ST_AsText()`).

Answer (score 4):

PostGIS semantics for empty return values from overlay functions changed a while back. They now return empty geometries of specific type, rather than untyped `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION`s.  This is a good thing, because it allows the result to be passed to other functions (predicates and overlay functions don't support `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION`s as inputs).